# Azure VM Web Access

Tags: mysql, azure

I am constructing a scaling ETL process and am considering using small Azure VMs to do this, but can't tell from reading the documentation if these VMs have web access.

Example: one ETL process reads a web API and imports data into MySQL and another reads from an email account and imports the data.

Is Azure compatible with reading web APIs/email APIs inside these VMs - both for Linux and Windows?

Comment: Yes, a vm in azure has internet access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMs in azure have internet access, so grabbing data from external api is possible